# Comparing koma variable to string

Tags: conditionals, koma-script

I can't quite figure out how to compare a koma variable with a string by using `\usekomavar{..}`.

I want to set another koma variable depending on the value of the first. So I want something like this

```
\newkomavar{xyz}
\newkomavar{abc}

\setkomavar{xyz}{yes}

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\usekomavar{xyz}}{yes}=0
   \setkomavar{abc}{yes}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{yeah}
\fi
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `\usekomavar` has a starred version and can take an optional argument. So it is not fully expandable. So it can not be used inside `\pdfstrcmp` or the KOMA-script command `\ifstr`.

I have asked Markus. The optional argument can be used for commands like `\MakeUppercase` which influences the contents of its argument (that is explained in the manual) but also for such a comparison.

I would use the KOMA-script command `\ifstr` to do the comparison:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\newkomavar{abc}
\newkomavar{xyz}
\setkomavar{xyz}{yes}

\begin{document}
\usekomavar[\ifstr]{xyz}{yes}
  {\setkomavar{abc}{yes}}% true part
  {\setkomavar{abc}{yeah}}% false part
\usekomavar{abc}

\bigskip
\usekomavar[\ifstr]{xyz}{other}
  {\setkomavar{abc}{true}}% true part
  {\setkomavar{abc}{false}}% false part
\textbf{\usekomavar[\MakeUppercase]{abc}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But you will get same result with `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp`:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\newkomavar{abc}
\newkomavar{xyz}
\setkomavar{xyz}{yes}

\begin{document}
\usekomavar[\ifnum\pdfstrcmp]{xyz}{yes}=0
   \setkomavar{abc}{yes}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{yeah}
\fi
\usekomavar{abc}

\bigskip
\usekomavar[\ifnum\pdfstrcmp]{xyz}{other}=0
   \setkomavar{abc}{true}
\else
   \setkomavar{abc}{false}
\fi
\textbf{\usekomavar[\MakeUppercase]{abc}}
\end{document}
```